# I'm trying to solve a fibonacci series using while loop in Python but I can't get the output which is a series of fibonacci numbers till 10000

Tags: python

What's wrong with my code? I can't get an output...

#Initializing the first and second value of a series

```
i = 0
first_value = 0
second_value = 1

# list and display fibonacci series using while loop

while (i < number):
    if (i <=1):
        result = i
    else:
        Next = first_value + second_value
        second_value = first_value
        second_value = result
    print(result)
    number = 10000
```

Comment: The value of `i` never changes. The condition `i<number` is always true.

Comment: See this [lovely debugging site](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for help.  Inserting a simple `print` or two -- to trace the loop execution and variable values -- would have shown the problem quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Fibonacy function using dynamic programming.

```
def fibonacy_dp(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    x = 0
    y = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        s = x + y
        x = y
        y = s
    return s
```

Your code has several problems:

- you should increase `i` in each iteration
- you should set second_value to `Next`
- The result is `Next`

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
first_value = 0
second_value = 1
# list and display fibonacci series using while loop
number = 100
while (i < number):
    
    if (i <=1):
        first_value,second_value=i,i
        result = i
    else:
        Next = first_value + second_value
        first_value=second_value
        second_value = Next
        result = Next
    print(result)
    
    i+=1
```